# Nano Jetson Jetpack 4.6.1 can't install right h5py version?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

I have a Nano Jetson and flashed it with the latest available Jetpack version from here: https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/learn/get-started-jetson-nano-devkit which is 4.6.1. Now when following this guide to install tensorflow: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/install-tf-jetson-platform/index.html I checked the version of tensorflow I need here: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/install-tf-jetson-platform-release-notes/tf-jetson-rel.html#tf-jetson-rel which is following command: `sudo pip3 install --extra-index-url https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/jp/v461 tensorflow==2.7.0+nv22.01` now when I run this command I get following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement h5py~=3.1.0 (from tensorflow) (from versions: 2.2.1, 2.3.0b1, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0b1, 2.4.0, 2.5.0, 2.6.0, 2.7.0rc2, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0, 2.10.0, 3.0.0rc1, 3.0.0, 3.1.0)                                                           
ERROR: No matching distribution found for h5py~=3.1.0
```

which doesn't even make sense, since 3.1.0 is in the list of available versions. When I try to manually install h5py 3.1.0 it fails a few times and keeps trying to install older versions after which it finally successfully installs h5py version 2.10.0, which is obviously too old for the version needed for the tensorflow version for my jetpack version. How can I install tensorflow on my nano jetson with Jetpack version 4.6.1?

Answer (score 0):

The right tutorial is not linked under the official page, but in a forum post: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/official-tensorflow-for-jetson-nano/71770, with this it works

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev hdf5-tools libhdf5-dev zlib1g-dev zip libjpeg8-dev liblapack-dev libblas-dev gfortran
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install -U pip testresources setuptools
$ sudo ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h
$ sudo pip3 install -U numpy==1.19.4 future mock keras_preprocessing keras_applications gast==0.2.1 protobuf pybind11 cython pkgconfig packaging
$ sudo pip3 install --extra-index-url https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/jp/v461 tensorflow
```